# Ruby on Rails form errors not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a basic app to create and store recipes to practice and can't seem to display errors under my forms, simple example of what I have below -

recipes_controller.rb (relevant sections )

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
  @recipe.save
  redirect_to '/create_recipe'
end

private  
def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

recipe.rb(model)

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :ingredients
    has_many :steps

    validates_presence_of :title
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
    <div class="new_recipe_form">

      <% if @recipe.errors.any? %>
        <div class="form_error">
          <ul>
            <% @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%='Error: ' +  msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>

      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description %>

    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form with no title, nothing happens. It doesn't create the recipe so I know the validator is working but no error appears.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are redirecting user to `new` action no matter if the recipe has been created or not. After redirect the `new` action is executed and `@recipe = Recipe.new` sets `@recipe` to new object that does not contain any pieces of information about recipe user was trying to create before (nor validation errors). What you should do is render new action inside create action instead of redirecting. Something like this could help:

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
  if @recipe.save
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

(I assumed you have show action in your controller and redirected user to show action after successful creation. If this is not a proper behaviour just change `redirect_to @recipe` to whatever you want)

Comment: I think you may have got the render and redirect the wrong way around, but I switched them and now it is working! thank you

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you for pointing this out. Fixed so it won't be confusing for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

P. Boro got it but I think they got the if and else the wrong way around, my controller now looks like this and it's working!

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
  if @recipe.save
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Good to hear you got the solutions.

But you are brand new to Ruby and Rails so What I would like to suggest you, first go through [scaffold](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding) generator so that you will get the basic idea of MVC and How CRUD operation works in rails?

After generating code with scaffold explore it deeply.